# Update related data when AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to update a simple model:

```
public class DayOff
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public List<User> Users { get; set; }

        public DayOff()
        {
            Users = new List<User>();
        }
    }
```

my service layer is:

```
public void Update(DayOff dayOff, IEnumerable<int> users)
{
    var dayOffToUpdate = _db.DayOff.Include("Users").Single(d => d.Id == dayOff.Id);
    dayOffToUpdate.Users.Clear();

    _db.Entry(dayOffToUpdate).CurrentValues.SetValues(dayOff);

    dayOffToUpdate.Users = _db.User.Where(u => users.Contains(u.Id)).ToList();

    foreach (var user in dayOffToUpdate.Users)
    {
        _db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

but it is NOT updating the users, so how can I?

Comment: Why do you say "tracking is off"?

Comment: @GertArnold When I set AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false; I'll change it.

Comment: I assume you ensured that `dayOffToUpdate.Users` contains elements?